# didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and post data at the same time

Tags: ios, authentication, post, https

I can manage to do didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and I get response back from server.

However, I have one issue. I am doing for login page.

Our procedure is that we will first do authentication. At the same time, we also post some data to server. If that data is not received, we cannot proceed to next step.

My problem is that I can manage to do authentication and that process is finished first. That means authentication is finished before I have posted data. I would like to know how to do authentication and post data at the same time.

Curl command will be something like this. 
     **curl -k --user username:password --data 'username=username&password=password’ https://ktl.no-ip.biz/test/public/index.php/api/v1**

If the posted data is not received,

**receivedString is {"error":true,"message":"NO Username and/or password given."}**

If it is received,
**receivedString is {"error":false,"message":"Login success."}**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

NSLog(@"didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");



if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    NSLog(@"NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust");

    NSURLCredential *credentail = [NSURLCredential
                                   credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                   password:@"password"
                                   persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentail forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    [self loginToCustomServer]; //this will post to server


}
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}    




-(void)loginToCustomServer 
{
NSLog(@"loginToCustomServer");

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",IP_ADDRESS,login_path]]];

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            username.text, @"username",
                            password.text,@"password",
                            nil];


[httpClient postPath:login_path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);


    responseFromLogin =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error: Nil];


    NSLog(@"responseFromLogin is %@",responseFromLogin);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error in loginToCustomServer: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];


}
```

Comment: post your code what you have tried

Comment: Yes. I have now posted. How shall I do?

Comment: what is mean post data to server the authentication once it going  success state or any state failure/success

Comment: I am trying to do like this curl.                                             curl -k --user username:password --data 'username=username&password=password’ https://ktl.no-ip.biz/test/public/index.php/api/v1                                  If that post data is not received, server will give one response. If posted data is received, server will give another.

Comment: oh i m sorry. I think I am messing up the code and didn't understand what it means really. I now understand. I just need to add this after httpclient declaration.      [httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"user1" password:@"pass1"];